# Ignore() function usage issue in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cin, getline

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ios> 
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int x;
   char str[80];
   cout << "Enter a number and a string:\n";
   cin >> x;
   cin.ignore('\n');

   cin.getline(str,80); 
   cout << "You have entered:\n";
   cout << x << endl;
   cout << str << endl;
}
```

I am facing an issue with the ignore function where using 
`cin.ignore('\n');` results in an output where I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times to print statements (for less number of characters) or else it cuts some of the initial characters from my string in the output (in case of more number of characters). Like these:

[image]

[image]

while using `cin.ignore();` results in the correct output.

[image]

Isn't it the same to use either of these as `'\n'` discards new line character and an `()` empty bracket also dicards the last character (or new line character as here).

Also, when should we use `cin.getline()` and `getline(cin,   )`?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, just use text. There are enough formatting options to make it look good. Concerning your code, as a general approach for interactive programs like yours, use `getline()` exclusively. If you need an integer, read a line nonetheless and then parse that line. Switching between formatted (`>>`) input and unformatted input isn't worth it, as you're seeing yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ignore()` incorrectly.

It has 2 optional parameters - a max `count` of characters to ignore, and a `delim` character to stop ignoring on, **in that order**:

```cpp
basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
```

`ignore()` will skip characters until the `delim` is encountered, or the `count` has been reached, whichever occurs first.

You are passing `'\n'` to the `count` parameter, not the `delim` parameter. `'\n'` has a numeric value of 10 when converted to an integer. So you are telling `ignore()` to skip 10 characters.

In your 1st example, that is the line break after `6`, followed by the next 9 characters `gautamgoy`. Thus the `getline()` afterwards starts reading at `al` and ends on the next line break.

In your 2nd example, that is the line break after `4`, followed by the next 6 characters `grgzed`, followed by the next 3 line breaks. Thus the `getline()` afterwards ends on the next line break as there are no characters to read.

In your 3rd example, calling `ignore()` with no parameters will skip only 1 character, the line break after `6`, leaving the rest of the characters `gautam goyal` for `getline()` to read up to the next line break.

When ignoring characters up to the next line break, regardless of how many characters there are, use this instead:

```cpp
#include <limits>

cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: @Remy_Lebeau what about my second question of difference between cin.getline() and getline(cin,   ).

Comment: @GautamGoyal it is simply the difference between using a `char[]` array vs a `std::string` object